# python get dictionary values list as list if key match

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list and dictionary:

```
match_keys = ['61df50b6-3b50-4f22-a175-404089b2ec4f']

locations = {
  '2c50b449-416e-456a-bde6-c469698c5f7': ['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138'], 
  '61df50b6-3b50-4f22-a175-404089b2ec4f': [
   '7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f', '6d06ee0a-7447-4726-822f-942b9e12c9ce'
   ]
}
```

If I want to search 'locations' for keys that match in the match_keys list and extract their values, to get something like this...

```
['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f', '6d06ee0a-7447-4726-822f-942b9e12c9ce']
```

...what would be the best way?

Comment: I'm not following what the problem is here. Are you looking for a plain key lookup, i.e. ``locations[match_keys[0]]``?

Comment: So for each key match find their corresponding values in the dictionary locations.

Comment: Okay, and what about it is the problem you are asking here? There's only a single key and a single result list in your example, so it's hard to say what needs solving here. Do you have very many keys to look up and cannot do it sequentially? Is there some efficiency consideration, such as most keys not being in the dict? Some post-processing challenge, such as flattening the results or eliminating duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `match_keys` and use `dict.get` to get the values under each key:

```
out = [v for key in match_keys if key in locations for v in locations[key]]
```

Output:

```
['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f', '6d06ee0a-7447-4726-822f-942b9e12c9ce']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get a list of list.  [['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f', '6d06ee0a-7447-4726-822f-942b9e12c9ce']] Is there a way just to have the one list.  ['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f', '6d06ee0a-7447-4726-822f-942b9e12c9ce']

Comment: This will fail with an error if the key is not in the dict.

Comment: I think for the intended purposes, the key will always be in the dict.

Comment: @MarkR That's important information which should be in the question, not some answer comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in locations.items():
    if key == match_keys[0]:
        print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over keys and get value by [].

```
res = []
for key in matched_keys:
  res.append(matched_keys[key])
```

or if you dont want list of lists you can use extend()

```
res = []
for key in matched_keys:
  res.extend(matched_keys[key])
```